# Torque and Angular Momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, torque

An ice skater is spinning in a circle with an angular velocity, $\omega$, and rotational inertia $I$. Let's say that the skater then pulls his arms directly inwards at a constant rate over a time of $t$ seconds, so that his rotational inertia is halved to $\frac{I}{2}$. There are forces from the skater's muscles going through his center, but the lever arm is 0 so net-torque is 0. By conservation of angular momentum, his angular velocity would be doubled to $2\omega$.

Another equation states that $\tau = I\alpha$. Since angular velocity is changing, there is surely an angular acceleration. The skater also definitely has a non-zero rotational inertia, which implies there is a net-torque on the system.

This is a contradiction. Where have I gone wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93493/where-does-a-spinning-figure-skaters-energy-go-when-she-slows-down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from this [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Definition_and_relation_to_angular_momentum), the relation between torque and angular acceleration is derived in this way:

The unbalanced torque on a body along axis of rotation determines the rate of change of the body's angular momentum,

$$\boldsymbol{\tau} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
where $L$ is the angular momentum vector and $t$ is time. If multiple torques are acting on the body, it is instead the net torque which determines the rate of change of the angular momentum:

$$\boldsymbol{\tau}_1 + \cdots + \boldsymbol{\tau}_n = \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\mathrm{net}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
For rotation about a fixed axis,

$$\mathbf{L} = I\boldsymbol{\omega}$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $\omega$ is the angular velocity. It follows that

$$\boldsymbol{\tau}_{\mathrm{net}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{L}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}(I\boldsymbol{\omega})}{\mathrm{d}t} = I\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d}t} = I\boldsymbol{\alpha}$$
where $α$ is the angular acceleration of the body, measured in $rad/s^2$.

*Your answer specifically lies in the following paragraph*:

> This equation has the limitation that the torque equation describes
>   the instantaneous axis of rotation or center of mass for any type of
>   motion – whether pure translation, pure rotation, or mixed motion. $I$
>   = Moment of inertia about the point which the torque is written (either instantaneous axis of rotation or center of mass only). If
>   body is in translatory equilibrium then the torque equation is the
>   same about all points in the plane of motion.

Few points I would like to emphasise on:

1. In general, in the formula, $\mathbf{L} = I\boldsymbol{\omega}$, $I$ is the moment of inertia tensor and depending on the axis of rotation and our assumption of co-ordinate axes, it becomes a scalar or a vector and so on.
2. In $\boldsymbol{\tau}_{\mathrm{net}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{L}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}(I\boldsymbol{\omega})}{\mathrm{d}t} = I\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d}t} = I\boldsymbol{\alpha}$, $I$ is a constant, hence it is taken out of the term $\frac{\mathrm{d}(I\boldsymbol{\omega})}{\mathrm{d}t}$ to form the term $I\frac{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\omega}}{\mathrm{d}t}$.But here $I$ is not constant. So you cannot use that formula.

Comment: Top-notch explanation!

Comment: $\frac{dL}{dt}=I\frac{d\omega}{dt}+\omega \frac{dI}{dt}$